# What is wrong with my layoutInflater?

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

Following this tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6vE8fqQPTE&index=8&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE8TUoCyjomGFqzTFcJ05OaC. My code is fine, saying there are no errors, but when I run this on the emulator in Android Studio 3.0.1, the App crashes. I'm using compiled/targetedSDK 27, minimum 18. Emulator API 27.

StackTrace:

```
02-15 13:07:56.424 26483-26483/com.example.sjdav.listadapter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.sjdav.listadapter, PID: 26483
                                                                               android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Can't convert value at index 4 to dimension: type=0x12
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 4 to dimension: type=0x12
                                                                                   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:730)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7794)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1976)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1874)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1872)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                   <!--PROBLEM LINE--> at com.example.sjdav.listadapter.PersonListAdapter.getView(PersonListAdapter.java:63)</--PROBLEM LINE-->
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2365)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:847)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1826)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2164)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:761)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19659)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6075)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2496)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2212)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
```

XML Activities: activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sjdav.listadapter.MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_list_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context="com.example.sjdav.listadapter.PersonListAdapter">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="33.3"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="66.6">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@+id/textView2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

PersonListAdapter Class:

```
public class PersonListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

        private static final String TAG = "PersonListAdapter";

        private Context mContext;
        private int mResource;
        private int lastPosition = 1;

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView name;
            TextView birthday;
            TextView sex;
            // ImageView icon;
            // ProgressBar progressBar;
            // int position;
        }

        public PersonListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Person> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            mContext = context;
            mResource = resource;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            // Get the persons information
            String name = getItem(position).getName();
            String birthday = getItem(position).getBirthday();
            String sex = getItem(position).getSex();

            // Create the person object with the information
            Person person  = new Person(name, birthday, sex);

            Log.d(TAG, "getView: PersonListAdapter Person created.");

            // Create the anim View
            final View result;

            // ViewHolder Object
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            // Create the LayoutInflater
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                Log.d(TAG, "getView: before convertView.");
                <!--PROBLEM LINE-->convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);</--PROBLEM LINE-->
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                viewHolder.birthday = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                viewHolder.sex = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                result = convertView;
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                result = convertView;
            }


            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.load_down_anim : R.anim.load_up_anim);
            result.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;

            viewHolder.name.setText(person.getName());
            viewHolder.birthday.setText(person.getBirthday());
            viewHolder.sex.setText(person.getSex());

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

MainActivity Class:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: startedMain");

        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Person m1 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m2 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m3 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m4 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m5 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m6 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m7 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m8 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m9 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m10 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m11 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m12 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m13 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m14 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m15 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m16 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m17 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m18 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m19 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");
        Person m20 = new Person("John", "01-01-2000", "male");

        // Create ArrayList of Person Objects

        ArrayList<Person> personArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        personArrayList.add(m1);
        personArrayList.add(m2);
        personArrayList.add(m3);
        personArrayList.add(m4);
        personArrayList.add(m5);
        personArrayList.add(m6);
        personArrayList.add(m7);
        personArrayList.add(m8);
        personArrayList.add(m9);
        personArrayList.add(m10);
        personArrayList.add(m11);
        personArrayList.add(m12);
        personArrayList.add(m13);
        personArrayList.add(m14);
        personArrayList.add(m15);
        personArrayList.add(m16);
        personArrayList.add(m17);
        personArrayList.add(m18);
        personArrayList.add(m19);
        personArrayList.add(m20);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: personArrayList created.");

        // Person List Adapter
        PersonListAdapter adapter = new PersonListAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_view, personArrayList);

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Person Class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String birthday;
    private String sex;

    public Person(String name, String birthday, String sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sjdav.listadapter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The exception in the StackTrace points to layoutInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false). I'm not familiar with this. At the top the Stack:

Process: com.example.sjdav.listadapter, PID: 26483                                                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Can't convert value at index 4 to dimension: type=0x12
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 4 to dimension: type=0x12.

So some conversion error is taking place and I cannot isolate it. Please Help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: try removing the line text alignmemt center in linear layout of list item... and let me know

Comment: you have already given gravity center.. and i doubt u can pass a resource int value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `custom_list_view.xml`. Below `TextView` margin property creating this `Exception`

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@+id/textView2"/>
```

Check this line

```
android:layout_marginTop="@+id/textView2"
```

`@+id/textView2` this is not a valid margin value.

StackTrace Log also saying this.

```
   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 4 to dimension: type=0x12
               at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:730)
               at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7794)
```

Use a valid value.

Comment: Bingo son! So simple. Thanks.

Comment: You are most Welcome

Answer (score 0):

Provide a value in `dp` for `layout_marginTop` as in

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```